# printf just before a delay doesn't work in C

Tags: c, printf

Does anyone know why if i put a printf just before a delay it waits until the delay is finished before it prints de message?

Code1 with sleep():

```
int main (void)
{
    printf ("hi world");
    system("sleep 3");    
}
```

Code2 with a self implemented delay:

```
void delay(float sec)
{
    time_t start;
    time_t current;
    time(&start);
    do{
        time(&current);
    }while(difftime(current,start) < sec);
}
int main (void)
{
    printf ("hi world");
    delay(3);    
}
```

And if:

```
printf ("hi world");
delay(3);    
printf ("hi world");
delay(3);
```

it waits until the sum of sleeps and then it prints the messages at the same time

Why does this happen?

**UPDATE: I writed delay("sleep 3") when i called delay, i meant delay(3). Corrected**

Comment: Also, for better delay functionality, consider the standard POSIX `sleep()` function, declared in `unistd.h`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the standard output is not flush until you output a '\n' char.

try printf ("hi world\n");

Comment: You are right ;).You bith are right (Ben & FigBug). Thx a lot for the quick answer ;)

Comment: I don't think simply adding a \n is a guarantee that the output will be flushed.  I just happens to work for you, in this case.  Better to use fflush() as FigBug suggests.

Answer (score 21):

printf buffers it's output until a newline is output.

Add a [fflush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fflush)(stdout); to flush the buffers on demand.

Comment: Could you please provide an example such that it is clear when and where to place the `fflush` command. Thank You

Answer (score 8):

Normally, standard output is buffered until you either:

- output a `\n` character
- call `fflush(stdout)`

Do one of these things before calling `delay()` and you should see your output.

Comment: Note that writing a newline typically only flushes the output if stdout is a terminal; if it's being redirected to a file, writing a newline will not cause it to flush.

Answer (score 1):

When you call printf, you don't print anything until really necessary: until either the buffer fulls up, or you add a new line. Or you explicitly flush it.

So, you can either do

```
printf("Something\n");
delay();
```

or

```
printf("Something");
fflush(stdout);
delay();
```

Answer (score -1):

Technically that shouldn't even compile. In the `delay("sleep 3")` call you're trying to convert a `const char *` to a `float`. It should be:

```
void delay (float sec)
{
    // ...
}

delay(3);
```

Comment: It will compile, but it will treat a pointer as a float, which is probably going to do bad things. It won't compile if you crank up your compiler's warnings sufficiently.

Comment: @Chris yeah i figured it might even just convert the pointer to a float, but like you said, it ain't a good thing!

Comment: The compiler would probably at least complain about it anyway

Comment: i meant delay(3). Type error ;), i just updated the question. Thx for make me note it